# Python bypassing/ignoring else statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

The intent is to continuously prompt for user input and search the name in a csv file, return the row where it is, and if the name isn't in the file, add the address for the name inputted  by the user to a new row in the file.
The problem is that the `else` statement is completely ignored and the script runs both parts every time.

```
import csv

b = [None] * 2

while True:
    a = input("Enter name: ")
    with open("addresses.csv") as f_obj:
        reader = csv.reader(f_obj, delimiter=":")
        for row in reader:
            if a in row:
                print(row)
            else:
                with open("addresses.csv", "a+", newline="") as f:
                    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=":")
                    temp = input(f"Enter {a}'s address:")
                    b[0] = a
                    b[1] = temp
                    writer.writerow(b)
```

desired behaviour:

````
content of addresses.csv before running script: 
name:street1
```
user input: name
output: name:street1

user input: test
output: "Enter test's address: "
user input: street2
```
content of addresses.csv after running script: 
name:street1
test:street2
````

Comment: Step through your code in a debugger please. The problem will become immediately obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider that each row corresponds to a different entry. Right now, your if-else statement is executed on each row. So, say your file looks like this:

```
Alice,Address1
Bob,Address2
```

If we're looking for Alice, the first iteration of the for-loop will take the `if` path. But, since we don't stop searching (with something like `break`), we move on to the second row as well. Alice isn't Bob, so we take the `else` path. Note that, if we had 3 entries in the file, we would run the `else` statement twice. A similar problem happens if we searched for Bob instead of Alice.

My suggested (and untested) fix is below.

```py
import csv

b = [None] * 2

while True:
    a = input("Enter name: ")
    with open("addresses.csv") as f_obj:
        reader = csv.reader(f_obj, delimiter=":")
        found = False
        for row in reader:
            if a in row:
                print(row)
                found = True
                break
        if not found:
            with open("addresses.csv", "a+", newline="") as f:
                writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=":")
                temp = input(f"Enter {a}'s address:")
                b[0] = a
                b[1] = temp
                writer.writerow(b)
```